# Disagreement with calculus teacher on a recent test

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

I had a calculus quiz recently and there was a specific Yes/No question that keeps confusing me and I don't understand my teacher's point.

The question goes:
A point on the graph f where f ' is not defined, extreme values can occur on that point.  (Yes  /  No)

I gave examples of functions such as f(x)=x^(1/3) to show that the answer was "No" because in such a function where the derivative is undefined an extreme value is not present (even though a critical point is present),

Is this a flaw in my logic and understanding or is the case I'm coming up with just a deviance from the norm.
Would really appreciate if someone could clear my concept and help me with this.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: An example is $f(x)=|x|$. The derivate is not defined at $x_0=0$, nevertheless the function has a (global) minimum at $x_0=0$

Comment: Consider $y=|x|$. Where is the global minimum?

Comment: You have to read "can" correctly.  S/he didn't say "must."

Comment: @Vasya We had the same idea simultaneously :)

Comment: @Peter: Great minds... :)

Comment: Ahhhhh ... I get it now, thanks guys :)

Comment: Avoid questions with scandalous titles such as "HELP!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You exhibited an example that shows that "a point where $f'$ is not defined *might* not be an extremum". But it doesn't say that it *cannot* be an extremum.

My example is $f(x)=|x|$. The derivative is undefined at $x=0$, but this point is the (global) minimum. Hence I proved that "a point where $f'$ is not defined *can* be an extremum".

Comment: Just wondering, if we think of the 1st derivative as the rate of change, what would it mean to say that the rate of change of a function is not defined at a point of the function's domain? This may be outside the scope of this question, but it just occurred to me. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @NoChance: seems obvious, no ?